# CSS Menu Hover in a Wordpress site

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I have a [site](http://aaron.wordpresstiger.com) where I'm trying to fix the hover menu, which you can see doesn't hovers correctly and rollover's the border of each menu. as well as the last menu "CONTACT" when hovered doesn't fits the whole space or we can say it doesn't roll over with full space when hovered.

Image of the problem :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uP8US.png]

How to solve this?

Comment: could you show us the code? looks like it has a fixed width to hover

Comment: Sure thing mate, here you go: http://aaron.wordpresstiger.com/wp-content/themes/custom_theme/style.css

Comment: You should edit your question to add your code.

Comment: due to less reputation points it's not letting me add more than 2 links. but I've added the link of code in my last comment.

Comment: The reasoning for this is because you are applying the "hover state image" to the anchor tag, because that anchor tag is nested inside your LI it appears over the top of your LI, covering up your borders.  Another problem you have is that your anchor tags ALL have a border-radius on all corners, when only the first and last ones should.  As for fixing this, you have a few options, one way would be to decrease the size of the anchor tag in order to let the border show through.  I would suggest instead to start over and code this entire thing in CSS and drop the images.

Comment: Another suggestion would be to keep your hover state on the same tag as the bg image.  In this case your bg image is on the LI, so put your hover graphic [or css] on the LI, rather than the anchor tag.

Comment: If you can give me the code to fix it up, that'd be perfect! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi ther is your new part of css

```
#access {
clear: both;
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 0 auto 6px;
width: 90%;
margin-left: 40px;
height: 55px;
border-radius: 8px;
}

#access ul {
font-size: 21px;
list-style: none;
margin: 0 0 0 -0.5em;
padding-left: 0;
border-radius: 8px;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
padding: 0;
height: 55px;
display: block;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
background-image: url('background-image.png');
}
#access li {
float: left;
position: relative;
border-style: solid;
width: 25% !important;
background-image: url('border-left-image.png');
background-position: right;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: block;
}
```

In http://aaron.wordpresstiger.com/wp-content/themes/custom_theme/style.css on line 601 that is your problem: width: 24% (remove this line from your css)

```
#access li:last-of-type, li#menu-item-31{
    border-right: none !important;
    width:24% !important;
    background-image:none;
}

#access li:hover:last-of-type, li#menu-item-31{
    border-right: none !important;
    width:24% !important;
    background-image:none;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Add to your css:

```
#menu-item-31 a {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Barkek, Yes this worked. The Second problem is solved but the first problem remains still there. when hovered it takes the place of right border of the menu. I just wanted menu hover to look like exactly like http://officialfacebooklikes.com - I really Appreciate your time and response. Thanks man!